# Why my ASP Website content is not being crawled by Google?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

While testing using following tools .

1.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php

2.feedthebot.com/tools/

It shows that spider not seeing any text in  my website http://wwww.vamartinc.com.

I run the test after inserting some text just below the body tag, even then the results appear as spider sees no text.
Even menu bar items text is not being found by the bot.

My robots text is not restricting bots to fetch my content and meta as index , follow.
Content

Please help to resolve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fetch as googlebot in webmaster tools to check the crawling and rendering of your pages. Third-party tools are not googlebot.

Your site is being indexed :

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Avamartinc.com

and searching for a word on your site brings up the relevant page :

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Avamartinc.com#q=site:vamartinc.com+Thennezhuthu

Comment: I thought those tools can be trusted .Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use **Google Webmaster Tools**: http://www.google.com/webmasters/. It will answer to all your questions above (robots.txt inspection, site visibility and index status, detailed crawling errors, etc...).